# RegQueryValueEx gets a weird value

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I am trying to retrieve some values from the registry.
Here is the full path:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes]
"ThemeChangesMousePointers"=0x00000001 (1)

And here is my code:

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD dwDisp = REG_DWORD;
DWORD dwType;
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);
DWORD dwValue = 0;
DWORD dwReturn;
char buffer[255] = {0};
//char* buffer;
//DWORD buffer = 0;
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buffer);

if( RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes")
    ,&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    dwType = REG_DWORD;
    if( RegQueryValueEx(hKey,_T("ThemeChangesMousePointers"),0, &dwType, (LPBYTE) buffer, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Key value is: %d \n", buffer);
        printf("GetLastError reports %d \n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Cannot query for key value \n");
    }
}
```

I have tried debugging and it seems like my buffer output variable is giving me a weird output:

Key value is: 2554292
Error is 0

Every time I run the code again, I get different values. How can I get the real value and not a different one?

EDIT: Post above has been edited to ask a different question.

Also, if this isn't enough code, I can add more.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetLastError` when `RegQueryValueEx` already returns success?

Comment: Guess I didn't catch that, but I fixed the code. Now I am reading the key, but getting wrong values. How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911%28VS.85%29.aspx) does not call `SetLastError`, it returns it's error code directly.

> ### Return Value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
> If the function fails, **the return value is a system error code.**
> If the lpData buffer is too small to receive the data, the function returns ERROR_MORE_DATA.
> If the lpValueName registry value does not exist, the function returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

EDIT IN RESPPONSE TO COMMENT:

I initially answered your specific question, bit with regards to the code you posted, there are still several remaining problems:

- You're calling the deprecated method RegOpenKey rather than RegOpenKeyEx.
- You're trying to read an integer but you're reading it as a char * string. This is the most likely cause of the problems you're getting... the function's returning an integer but you're printing it as a string.
- Your IF conditional is backwards

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD dwDisp = REG_DWORD;
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);
DWORD dwValue = 0;
DWORD dwReturn;
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(DWORD);

if( RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes"
    ,0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    DWORD error = RegQueryValueExW(hKey,L"ThemeChangesMousePointers",0,0, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&dwReturn), &dwBufSize);
    if(error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Key value is: %d \n", dwReturn);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Cannot query for key value; Error is: %d\n", error);
    }
}
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

Comment: So I put this in my code, but I get:

Key value is: 2554292
Error is 0

I guess it's reading a value now but it isn't the one I am looking for. How can I get the hexadecimal value?

Comment: Thanks! If I had 15 reputation, I'd uprank your answer.